# NotesTimer causes the whole lotus client to flicker

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a timer that talks to java objects through LS2J. It has only to call some getters of the java objects and to update the GUI with new values. This causes the GUI in iNotes Client to show the "Busy" cursor very shortly when the timer ticks. I is really annoying because it occurs even when another window is open and even in the designer.

I actually have to expect that the functionality in the timer event will get more complicated in the future, so I don't want to solve the problem by making my handler lighter.

Is there a way to tell iNotes client not to show this cursor or even an alternative way to make this regular check without timers?

Comment: Are you sure you mean iNotes? Because there's no client side LotusScript execution in the web client.

Answer (score 2):

The NotesTimer class in Notes client (not iNotes) does take over the foreground when it triggers, so there will be a bit of a delay if you do something that takes time to execute. It's possible to set up the Notes client to execute background scheduled agents in local database replicas, so that might be an option. You can to the heavy lifting in background and deposit the results somewhere -- say, in a profile document -- that can be accessed quickly by the UI code.
Alternately, you could try a XPages in the client application. I believe it can do partial refreshes while other stuff is going on.

Comment: The agent might help, but its scheduling times are too coarse, its minimum time unit is a minute. The timer I need has to update the GUI with the result of an upload operation taking place in the background. I even found the one-second minimum of the timer interval too long.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I simplified the functionality of the Java call by preparing the data so that the timer only has to read the results. I also made the timer run every 3 seconds instead of 1.

Now I don't see any flicker!